# Accessing the parent of a node's parent in a binary tree

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree struct like this:

```
typedef struct Tree{
    long int key;
    struct Tree *left, *right, *parent;

}Tree;
```

I'm using a pointer (parent) to keep track of the node's parent.

After insert some nodes, I'm having some troubles.

The result tree is:

```
    3
 /     \
1       11
 \     / 
  2   8
```

```
when I try to access (8)->parent, I get 11... that's right.

When I try to access (11)->parent, I get 3... all good.

But if I try (8)->parent->parent the result is NOT 3
```

Does anyone have any clues why it is not giving the node 3?

Comment: There's no way to know what is wrong unless you show your code.

Comment: That does not sound right. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How can you get 11, when you do (8)->parent? You should get 11 only via (8)->parent.key.

Comment: I actually do (8)->parent.key. What i'm saying is (8)->parent->parent is pointing to NULL instead of pointing to the node containing the key 3. Thanks anyway